# Python boto, list contents of specific dir in bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I have S3 access only to a specific directory in an S3 bucket.

For example, with the `s3cmd` command if I try to list the whole bucket:

```
    $ s3cmd ls s3://bucket-name
```

I get an error: `Access to bucket 'my-bucket-url' was denied`

But if I try access a specific directory in the bucket, I can see the contents:

```
    $ s3cmd ls s3://bucket-name/dir-in-bucket
```

Now I want to connect to the S3 bucket with python boto. Similary with:

```
    bucket = conn.get_bucket('bucket-name')
```

I get an error: `boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden`

But if I try:

```
    bucket = conn.get_bucket('bucket-name/dir-in-bucket')
```

The script stalls for about 10 seconds, and prints out an error afterwards. Bellow is the full trace. Any idea how to proceed with this?

Note question is about the boto version 2 module, not boto3.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_s3.py", line 7, in <module>
    bucket = conn.get_bucket('bucket-name/dir-name')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 471, in get_bucket
    return self.head_bucket(bucket_name, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 490, in head_bucket
    response = self.make_request('HEAD', bucket_name, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 633, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1046, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/connection.py", line 922, in _mexe
    request.body, request.headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 958, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1157, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `my-bucket-url/dir-in-bucket` instead of `my-bucket-url/my-bucket-url` in your script?

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake when trying to remove the actual bucket and dir names.

Answer (score 166, accepted):

For boto3

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket_name')

for object_summary in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="dir_name/"):
    print(object_summary.key)
```

Comment: You have to use use braces around object_summary.key to work in python3.

print (object_summary.key)

Comment: the weirdest part is Prefix="dir_name" worked find on my linux machine but to run this on lambda, it's important to use Prefix="dir_name/", I couldn't quite figure out why would the forward slash be significant to make it work on lambda.

Comment: How to limit the search depth?

Comment: maybe due to OS diffferecnces @yash

Comment: @Gulzar if you know exactly what you want, don't paginate it's expensive, you could use further str filters once you get all the file names without retrieving any data.

Comment: is there a way to do a wild-card search?

Comment: @johnk S3 only allows prefix based searches. More complex searches will have to be done client side. (meaning you'll have to do it yourself)

Answer (score 45):

By default, when you do a `get_bucket` call in boto it tries to validate that you actually have access to that bucket by performing a `HEAD` request on the bucket URL.  In this case, you don't want boto to do that since you don't have access to the bucket itself.  So, do this:

```
bucket = conn.get_bucket('my-bucket-url', validate=False)
```

and then you should be able to do something like this to list objects:

```
for key in bucket.list(prefix='dir-in-bucket'): 
    <do something>
```

If you still get a 403 Errror, try adding a slash at the end of the prefix.

```
for key in bucket.list(prefix='dir-in-bucket/'): 
    <do something>
```

**Note**: this answer was written about the boto version 2 module, which is obsolete by now. At the moment (2020), boto3 is the standard module for working with AWS. See this question for more info: [What is the difference between the AWS boto and boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32322503/what-is-the-difference-between-the-aws-boto-and-boto3)

Comment: thanks, this worked for me, I just needed to add a slash ('/') at the end of the bucket name, otherwise I still got the 403 error.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I approved your edit to my example. Glad its working for you.

Comment: Why is the trailing "/" needed? I can confirm that it is required in my instance, but I couldn't find documentation of it.

Answer (score 37):

Boto3 client:

```
import boto3

_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
_PREFIX = 'subfolder/'

client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                            aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

def ListFiles(client):
    """List files in specific S3 URL"""
    response = client.list_objects(Bucket=_BUCKET_NAME, Prefix=_PREFIX)
    for content in response.get('Contents', []):
        yield content.get('Key')

file_list = ListFiles(client)
for file in file_list:
    print 'File found: %s' % file
```

Using session

```
from boto3.session import Session

_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket'
_PREFIX = 'subfolder/'

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                  aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

client = session.client('s3')

def ListFilesV1(client, bucket, prefix=''):
    """List files in specific S3 URL"""
    paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects')
    for result in paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket, Prefix=prefix,
                                     Delimiter='/'):
        for content in result.get('Contents', []):
            yield content.get('Key')

file_list = ListFilesV1(client, _BUCKET_NAME, prefix=_PREFIX)
for file in file_list:
    print 'File found: %s' % file
```

Comment: In general: what is difference in going for boto3.resource or boto3.cleint or boto3.session based approach and which approach to be followed under what condition?

Comment: For any confusion, boto3.resource is preferred. Also here is the difference between client and resource: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42809096/difference-in-boto3-between-resource-client-and-session

Comment: this could use some explanation

Answer (score 12):

I just had this same problem, and this code does the trick.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
s3_bucket = s3.Bucket("bucket-name")
dir = "dir-in-bucket"
files_in_s3 = [f.key.split(dir + "/")[1] for f in 
s3_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=dir).all()]
```

Comment: this answer involves boto3, the original question was for the boto version 2 module. Nevertheless, by 2020 boto3 is the standard now

Comment: What .all() meens exactly ? According to documentation [link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.objects) `all() Creates an iterable of all Bucket resources in the collection.`. but it is never used with filter() ? How to have only folder in a prefix (without subfolder) ?
Thank you a lot @rob

Answer (score 8):

The following code will list all the files in specific dir of the S3 bucket:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def get_all_s3_keys(s3_path):
    """
    Get a list of all keys in an S3 bucket.

    :param s3_path: Path of S3 dir.
    """
    keys = []

    if not s3_path.startswith('s3://'):
        s3_path = 's3://' + s3_path

    bucket = s3_path.split('//')[1].split('/')[0]
    prefix = '/'.join(s3_path.split('//')[1].split('/')[1:])

    kwargs = {'Bucket': bucket, 'Prefix': prefix}
    while True:
        resp = s3.list_objects_v2(**kwargs)
        for obj in resp['Contents']:
            keys.append(obj['Key'])

        try:
            kwargs['ContinuationToken'] = resp['NextContinuationToken']
        except KeyError:
            break

    return keys
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done using:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
objects = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='bucket_name')
for obj in objects['Contents']:
  print(obj['Key'])
```

Comment: any way to get this to do folders?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to list objects of a specific prefix in S3 is to use `awswrangler`:

```
import awswrangler as wr
wr.s3.list_objects("s3://bucket_name/some/prefix/")
```

This will return a list of the objects stored in `some/prefix/`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list all the objects of a folder in your bucket, you can specify it while listing.

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_s3(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(AWS_BUCKET_NAME)
for file in bucket.list("FOLDER_NAME/", "/"):
    <do something with required file>
```

Comment: The OP mentioned that `get_bucket` was giving him a 403

Comment: How do I read the contents of one particular file to a variable from this?

Comment: @Rahul I guess file.read() should work. But then I will have to check it once.

Comment: @ChrisWue That could be because of wrong secret access key

Comment: OP has specific access to a file or folder within a bucket, but doesn't have access to a bucket.  I am in the same position, I can access files and folders within the AWS GUI, but I can't get anything done in boto3.