# What is the difference between the AWS boto and boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

I'm trying to learn the boto API and I noticed that there are two major versions/packages for Python: boto and boto3.

What is the difference between the AWS boto and boto3 libraries?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) package is the hand-coded Python library that has been around since 2006.  It is very popular and is fully supported by AWS but because it is hand-coded and there are so many services available (with more appearing all the time) it is difficult to maintain.

So, [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) is a new version of the boto library based on [botocore](https://github.com/boto/botocore).  All of the low-level interfaces to AWS are driven from JSON service descriptions that are generated automatically from the canonical descriptions of the services.  So, the interfaces are always correct and always up to date.  There is a resource layer on top of the client-layer that provides a nicer, more Pythonic interface.

The boto3 library is being actively developed by AWS and is the one I would recommend people use if they are starting new development.

Comment: In practice AWS services that don't have a Resource layer in boto3 are often easier to handle in boto.  YMMV

Comment: Boto3 was made generally available on 06/22/2015

Comment: As of mid-22022, boto is depreciated in favour of boto3.

Comment: @codenada Maybe 20,000 years earlier than that.

Comment: @MikeF No, Amazon is just that much committed to backwards compatibility.