# How do I read a JSON file present in s3 bucket using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have kept some JSON files in s3 bucket and I want to read the contents of those JSON files using boto3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read file content from S3 bucket with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205481/read-file-content-from-s3-bucket-with-boto3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is probably a duplicate of [Already answered question right here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205481/read-file-content-from-s3-bucket-with-boto3)

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('test-bucket')
# Iterates through all the objects, doing the pagination for you. Each obj
# is an ObjectSummary, so it doesn't contain the body. You'll need to call
# get to get the whole body.
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    key = obj.key
    body = obj.get()['Body'].read()
```

To read from a particular folder you can try this

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my_bucket_name')

for object_summary in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix="dir_name/"):
    print(object_summary.key)
```

Credits - [M.Vanderlee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292145/python-boto-list-contents-of-specific-dir-in-bucket)

Comment: I tried the same but getting error as shown below:Attribute Error:'str object has no attribute 'óbjects'

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and show the code you're trying? @Champion

Comment: I got it how to read json file.Thanks for your help.One more query- if instead of whole bucket,I want to read json files from only a specific folder in bucket,then how to do it?

Comment: No worries my man! Can you accept my answer? Also where I've defined `key`,

Comment: Also where I've defined `key`,
just try `obj.all`. This should probably work.

Comment: Hey @Champion I have edited my answer to satisfy your new query, take a look at it now.