# How to read a csv file from s3 bucket using lambda function and boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I have s3 bucket and I have set a lambda function which will display contents of csv file when a csv file is uploaded to s3 bucket.S3 bucket is already set as a trigger for my lambda function. Can you please suggest and advise?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58597953/9931092

Comment: Where is the Lambda function supposed to "display contents of csv file" exactly?

Comment: cloudwatch logs

Comment: What are you exactly asking here? You already asked how to read JSON, wouldn't this be the same way? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59817196/how-to-read-a-json-file-present-in-s3-bucket-using-boto3

Comment: no it is not the same way

Comment: Is there any way to read a csv file from s3 bucket and then edit it by adding extra column and put that file back to s3 bucket using same lambda function.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AWS Lambda function is code that you write. You can make it do anything you wish.

For your first scenario of displaying a CSV file in CloudWatch Logs, the Lambda function should:

- Retrieve the name of the bucket and object from the `event` passed to the Lambda function
- **Download** the file from Amazon S3 to the `/tmp/` directory
- Read the CSV using normal Python code and `print()` the information that you wish to appear in CloudWatch Logs
- **Delete** the temporary file, so as not to consume too much disk space (there is a limit of 500MB of temporary disk space, and Lambda containers can be reused multiple times)

For your second question of "adding an extra column", the Lambda function should:

- Retrieve the name of the bucket and object from the `event` passed to the Lambda function
- **Download** the file from Amazon S3 to the `/tmp/` directory
- Manipulate the contents of the file however you wish, using Python code
- **Upload** the file to Amazon S3
- **Delete** the temporary file, so as not to consume too much disk space (there is a limit of 500MB of temporary disk space, and Lambda containers can be reused multiple times)

The code would look something like:

```py
import urllib
import boto3

# Connect to S3 and DynamoDB
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # Get the bucket and object key from the Event
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
    localFilename = '/tmp/file.txt'

    # Download the file from S3 to the local filesystem
    s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, localFilename)

    # Do stuff here with the local file (your code here!)
    pass

    # Upload modified file
    s3_client.upload_file(localFilename, bucket, key)
```

Comment: I know the steps but I want to include the add column in below code:

Comment: import json
import boto3
import csv


def lambda_handler(event, context):
   s3=boto3.client('s3')
   if event:
       file_obj=event['Records'][0]
       filename=str((file_obj)['s3']['object']['key'])
       print(filename)
       fileobj=s3.get_object(Bucket="danvan",Key=filename)
       file_content=fileobj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
       print(file_content)
       print(type(file_content))

Comment: The above code will read csv or any file as and when it is uploaded to s3 bucket using lambda function and display its contents,but my question is I want to add an extra column to my csv file using same lambda function and then save it back to s3?

Comment: My recommendation is to download the file, then modify it, then upload the file. For the middle part, you can write your own Python to modify the file however you wish. That part has nothing to do with Lambda, boto3 or AWS.

Comment: Is it possible to share a code on modifying csv file using lambda and send it back to s3

Comment: Actually I am facing issue while modifying a csv file stored in S3 because there is no write attribute with body

Comment: I have added some sample code showing how to download and upload the file. This is easier than using `body` and `streams`. You can add your own code in the middle that reads and modifies the local file.

Comment: But I want to automate the process.Downloading the file to a local directory and then making changes and then upload will increase manual work.What I want here is that as I read it using get_object,then I should be able to modify it using boto3 and then send it back to S3 so that it will work for all those files that hit my S3 bucket.

Comment: That is exactly what I am recommending. However, rather than using `get_object()`, my recommendation is to have the Lambda function download the file to local file storage within Lambda, then Lambda can perform the edit using code that you write, then upload the modified file. You will find this easier than manipulating the file as a stream.

Comment: But there is no local storage within lambda.Can you show it via code.I mean how you will modify the file.

Comment: AWS Lambda functions are given 500MB of storage in `/tmp/`. My code example above shows how to download the file from Amazon S3 that triggered the Lambda function and how to upload it again after it has been modified. The part that "modifies the file" has nothing to do with AWS or Lambda -- it is just normal code that you can write to do whatever you wish. You should start by writing it as a program on your own computer, then move that code into the Lambda function.

Comment: Thanks John,it worked.Can you help me with how can I remove the file from lambda local storage

Comment: If you always save to the same local filename, then there is no need to remove the file, since it will be overwritten during the next execution. However, if you wish to delete it, you can use `os.remove(localFilename)` (remember to `import os` first).