# Accessing specific files in S3 via Boto3 without permissions to higher level Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, boto3

Very annoying permissions issue here:

- I've been granted access to specific subfolders of an S3 bucket.
- I don't appear to have permissions to the bucket in general.
- I am able to navigate via AWS GUI web interface and
  upload/download/rename files as I wish.
- I cannot appear to get anything done via boto3 without running into
  permissions issues.

Anybody know a workaround for this?  If possible I'd like to be able to proceed without waiting on permissions to be granted.

Python Code:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id = 'ACCESSKEY',
    aws_secret_access_key = 'SECRET',
    region_name = 'us-east-1'
)

resource = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id = 'ACCESSKEY',
    aws_secret_access_key = 'SECRET',
    region_name = 'us-east-1'
)

client.download_file("BUCKETNAME", "/FOLDER/PATH/FILENAME.json", "LOCALFILENAME")
```

Response:

```
ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Note: A similar problem occurred in this post: [Python boto, list contents of specific dir in bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292145/python-boto-list-contents-of-specific-dir-in-bucket).  A solution from boto 2.x was to disable the check for permissions of the bucket via "validate = False", but that is obsolete now in boto3.  Looking for a similar type solution, I suppose.

Comment: `get_object` should work without HeadObject permissions. `download_file` is a convenience function.

Comment: Can you explain what is a higher level Bucket

Comment: **Translation:** The `download_file()` command probably uses several API calls, including `HeadObject` (for which you do not have permission). This is a "higher-level function", in that it uses several API calls to perform its operation. Try accessing the object using `get_object()` instead, which directly maps to a single API call. (In the AWS CLI, this equates to `aws s3api get-object`.)

Comment: @smac2020 mybucket is the bucket, mybucket/path/to/file.json is what I am able to access.