# s3.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'list_objects_v2'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

```
import boto3
resource = boto3.resource('s3') 
response = resource.buckets.all()
for buckets in response:
    print(buckets)
    myobjects=resource.list_objects_v2(bucket=buckets)
    for object in myobjects:
        print(object)
```

Comment: `list_objects_v2` is available on the `client`, not on the `resource`: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python boto, list contents of specific dir in bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27292145/python-boto-list-contents-of-specific-dir-in-bucket)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of using `boto3`:

- `client` methods map 1:1 with AWS API calls
- `resource` methods are more Pythonic

Here is your program using `resource` methods:

```py
import boto3
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3') 
buckets = s3_resource.buckets.all()
for bucket in buckets:
    print(bucket.Name)
    objects = bucket.objects.all()
    for object in objects:
        print(object.key)
```