# Amazon S3: How to get a list of folders in the bucket?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

The only thing I've found, it's this method [GET Bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html).
But I can't understand how can I get only a list of folders in the current folder. What prefix and delimiter do I need to use? Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For the sake of example, assume I have a bucket in the `USEast1` region called `MyBucketName`, with the following keys:

```
 temp/
 temp/foobar.txt
 temp/txt/
 temp/txt/test1.txt
 temp/txt/test2.txt
 temp2/
```

Working with folders can be confusing because S3 does not natively support a hierarchy structure -- rather, these are simply keys like any other S3 object.  Folders are simply an abstraction available in the S3 web console to make it easier to navigate a bucket.  So when we're working programatically, we want to find keys matching the dimensions of a 'folder' (delimiter '/', size = 0) because they will likely be 'folders' as presented to us by the S3 console.

*Note for both examples: I'm using the AWSSDK.S3 version 3.1 NuGet package.*

**Example 1: All folders in a bucket**

This code is modified from [this basic example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingNetSDK.html) in the S3 documentation to list all keys in a bucket. The example below will identify all keys that end with the delimiter character `/`, and are also empty.

```
IAmazonS3 client;
using (client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
{
    // Build your request to list objects in the bucket
    ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest
    {
        BucketName = "MyBucketName"
    };

    do
    {
        // Build your call out to S3 and store the response
        ListObjectsResponse response = client.ListObjects(request);

        // Filter through the response to find keys that:
        // - end with the delimiter character '/' 
        // - are empty. 
        IEnumerable<S3Object> folders = response.S3Objects.Where(x =>
            x.Key.EndsWith(@"/") && x.Size == 0);

        // Do something with your output keys.  For this example, we write to the console.
        folders.ToList().ForEach(x => System.Console.WriteLine(x.Key));

        // If the response is truncated, we'll make another request 
        // and pull the next batch of keys
        if (response.IsTruncated)
        {
            request.Marker = response.NextMarker;
        }
        else
        {
            request = null;
        }
    } while (request != null);
}
```

Expected output to console:

```
temp/
temp/txt/
temp2/
```

**Example 2: Folders matching a specified prefix**

You could further limit this to only retrieve folders matching a specified `Prefix` by setting the `Prefix` property on [ListObjectsRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingNetSDK.html).

```
ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest
    {
        BucketName = "MyBucketName",
        Prefix = "temp/"
    };
```

When applied to Example 1, we would expect the following output:

```
temp/
temp/txt/
```

**Further reading:**

- [S3 Documentation - Working With Folders](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html)
- [.NET SDK Documentation - ListObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingNetSDK.html)

Comment: Thak you for your detailed response. This code work for me, when I changing x.Size == 0 on x.Size == 1. But it does not recognize all folder, only a small part of them. I can't understand why that's happening. I'm exactly that my cycle goes over and over again until it reaches the end. But I can't get all of the folders. What can be the reason?

Comment: Maybe related to you changing Size to 1?  'Folders' are presented in this list call as S3 objects with no contents: they should be Size 0. You could simply remove size from the predicate if you're finding the objects you need without it.

Comment: If you're still having trouble after that, maybe make sure your ListObjectsRequest isn't limiting your request too much.  For example, if you specified a prefix... test your code without it to make sure it isn't limiting your request too much. If that doesn't work, feel free to ask a new question (this one is very clear as-is, we don't want to clutter it up) with an example of your bucket's structure and the request you're trying to make.

Comment: If I tried to delete size comparison, I have the same result when I write x.Size == 1. Can you look my code with my results? http://codeshare.io/4eBiJ
These are how it must look: http://snag.gy/HbLhK.jpg

Comment: `request.Delimiter` is unnecessary and may be causing trouble, try it without that.  It is interesting that `BF/Music/` seems to be getting skipped outright; could you do a sanity check and make sure it exists as you expect in the S3 bucket?  As for the subdirectories, if you don't want them you can simply filter your list further after retrieval via regex or matching a single slash, etc.

Comment: I'm completely sure that this directory existing. Aslo, under directories wich displayed as result of request, exist a lot of folders. But displayed only "BF/REFERENCE_TRACKS/" and  "BF/REFERENCE_TRACKS/MP3/". There are a lot of children-directories, but they aren't displaying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94366/discussion-between-neustart47-and-hyper-anthony).

Comment: @AnthonyNeace I'm getting an errror http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39106395/amazon-s3-list-objects?noredirect=1#comment65572638_39106395

Answer (score 11):

Using `prefix` of `the/path/to/read/` (note that there is *no* leading slash, but there *is* a trailing slash), and `delimiter` of `/`, you'll find all the folders within that folder inside `<CommonPrefixes>`.

> **CommonPrefixes**
>
> A response can contain `CommonPrefixes` only if you specify a delimiter. When you do, `CommonPrefixes` contains all (if there are any) keys between Prefix and the next occurrence of the string specified by delimiter. In effect, CommonPrefixes lists keys that act like subdirectories in the directory specified by `Prefix`. For example, if prefix is notes/ and delimiter is a slash (/), in notes/summer/july, the common prefix is notes/summer/. All of the keys rolled up in a common prefix count as a single return when calculating the number of returns. See MaxKeys.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively another simpler approach is using https://github.com/minio/minio-dotnet

Minio .Net implements minimal API's to work with Amazon S3 and other compatible storage solutions.

Following example shows how you can filter out only directories. Here the CommonPrefix is abstracted as a folder through the ListObjects() API.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Minio;
using Minio.Xml;

namespace Minio.Examples
{
    class ListObjects
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new MinioClient("https://s3.amazonaws.com", "ACCESSKEY", "SECRETKEY");

            var items = client.ListObjects("bucket");

            foreach (Item item in items)
            {
                if (item.IsDir)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("{0}", item.Key);
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What Anthony is missing here is that a folder doesn't necessarily have a key associated with it. If a file is created in S3, and given a key like "folder/name.ext", S3 will display a "folder" folder, but it doesn't have a key, meaning you're not getting it in your results.

The only way to catch these folders is to look at the keys themselves, and regex the key name for the "/" character. If I knew C# a little better, I'd write you a code sample, but for reference here's a [python example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41768271/4863406) I wrote on another question.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a delimiter of '/' to my parameters did the trick for me.

In case anyone needs a NodeJS solution this is what I used:

```
listdelim: function (path) {
    const params = {
        Bucket: process.env['bucket'],
        MaxKeys: 1000,
        Prefix: path,
        Delimiter: '/'
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.listObjectsV2(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack)
                reject(err)
            } else {
                resolve(data)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: if use delimiter of '/', result will in `response.CommonPrefixes` not in `response.S3Objects`

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't mind using a third-party open-source tool, you can use [rclone](https://rclone.org/)'s command [lsf](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_lsf/) which includes [--dirs-only and --recursive](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_lsf/#options).

1. [Install rclone](https://rclone.org/install/)
2. Set environment variables

   ```bash
   export AWS_REGION=eu-west-1
   export S3_BUCKET_NAME=my.private.bucket
   export S3_BUCKET_PREFIX=temp
   ```
3. Gets all directories under a given prefix; If the prefix is empty, the whole bucket will be scanned, which is not recommended for buckets with many objects. The exclude pattern `*/*/*/` means it will include only up to three subdirectories, not including the prefix, for example, include up to `temp/*/*/*/`.

   ```bash
   export \
   RCLONE_S3_REGION=${AWS_REGION} RCLONE_S3_PROVIDER=AWS \
   RCLONE_CONFIG_MYS3_TYPE=s3 && \
   rclone \
        --exclude "*/*/*/" \
        lsf mys3,env_auth:"${S3_BUCKET_NAME}/${S3_BUCKET_PREFIX}" \
        --recursive --dirs-only --config /dev/null
   ```

*NOTE-1*: Using the [env_auth option](https://rclone.org/s3/#authentication) enables using the default [AWS credentials providers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-precedence), as if you were using [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html). Bottom line, `env_auth` allows you to use `AWS_PROFILE`, or `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`+`ACCESS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` to authenticate.

*NOTE-2*: Adding the [--config /dev/null](https://github.com/rclone/rclone/issues/5222) option suppresses the warning message `NOTICE: Config file "/Users/username/.config/rclone/rclone.conf" not found - using defaults`

##### Bonus

In case the bucket is meant for build artifacts with branch based paths, here's a great example of how to list S3 directories with advanced exclusion patterns.

1. Set environment variables

   ```bash
   export AWS_REGION=eu-west-1
   export S3_BUCKET_NAME=my.private.bucket
   export S3_BUCKET_PREFIX=artifacts
   ```
2. Assuming the S3 artifacts dir structure is:

   - `artifacts/${version}/development/`
   - `artifacts/${version}/RC/`
   - `artifacts/${version}/feature/${branch_name}`
3. Examples of paths that will be **included**:

   - `artifacts/v1.1.1/development/`
   - `artifacts/v1.1.0/RC/`
   - `artifacts/v1.1.1/feature/jira-123-ticket/`
4. Examples of paths that will be **excluded**:

   - `artifacts/v1.1.1/development/docs/`
   - `artifacts/v1.1.0/RC/docs/`
   - `artifacts/v1.1.1/feature/jira-123-ticket/docs/`
5. Get list of directories with rclone

   ```bash
   export \
   RCLONE_S3_REGION=${AWS_REGION} RCLONE_S3_PROVIDER=AWS \
   RCLONE_CONFIG_MYS3_TYPE=s3 && \
   rclone \
        --exclude "*/development/*/" \
        --exclude "*/RC/*/" \
        --exclude "*/*/*/*/" \
        lsf mys3,env_auth:"${S3_BUCKET_NAME}/${S3_BUCKET_PREFIX}" \
        --recursive --dirs-only --config /dev/null
   ```

##### Troubleshooting

I had to unset the environment variable [AWS_CA_BUNDLE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html#:%7E:text=aws_ca_bundle) before using `rclone` to make it work.

```bash
unset AWS_CA_BUNDLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem today of the older AWS Api being obsolete and no given way to identify if its a folder out of the box.

Ended up writing an extension :

```
public static class S3Extensions {
    public static bool IsFolder(this S3Object @object) => @object.Key.EndsWith("/");
}
```

Will do the trick in dotNet anyway .