# Amazon S3 : List Objects

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have this code to list objects in the folder.

```
var accessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"];
            var secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"];

            using (AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1 ))
            {
                var prefix = string.Format(@"{0}/", uniqueKey);
                ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest();
                request.BucketName = bucketName;
                request.Delimiter = "/";
                request.Prefix = prefix;

                do
                {
                    ListObjectsResponse response = s3Client.ListObjects(request);
```

This throws an exception when I access the folders :

```
<uri>/bucketname/profile/ // Throws and exception key not found
<uri>/bucketname/profile/profile.png // This is OK
```

Image was created using the following path having a `READ` CannedACL.

```
<uri>/bucketname/profile//profile.png
```

**Error** 
`String key was not found`

**QUESTION**

1. Why i cannot access the folders (objects)?
2. Are folders need to set permissions individually for it to be accessible?

**UPDATE**
I solved the issue

> Bucket names should not have a `/` character
>   Client given me a bucket name with this format `sample/new`
>   But the true bucket name is only `sample`

Comment: *"This throws an exception"*  That seems unlikely.  `ListObjects()` is for discovery, and should succeed even in the absence of objects matching the prefix.  This exception is coming from elsewhere in your code.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the upload is working and I'm using the same client when listing the objects

Comment: Okay, but what I'm saying is it should not be possible for `ListObjects()` to throw a `key not found` exception, it should simply return an empty list, successfully.  What are you trying to do with folders?  They do not really exist in S3 -- that's what `delimiter` is for -- treating objects **as if** they were in folders, even though they aren't really there.  Creating a "folder" in the console only creates a zero-byte object whose key ends with the character `/`, for display.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes I got your point. For my question above I planned to get files inside folder. This is my bucketname `sample/new` and the prefix `Profile/`. Don't mind the bucket name because that's only a dummy but there is a slash on it

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I found the issue now and this makes me sad. Client informs me that this is the bucket name `sample/new` (this is a dummy, but actually bucket name is in this format). But a moment ago I read that slash in bucket name is not allowed. So I tried to remove the suffix `new` leaving the bucket name as `sample` and the error is gone. Very frustrating error, I spent many hours to debug this