# How to copy files from S3 using include pattern with underscore on the file name

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

How can I include the `_` (underscore) on the include pattern?

I have a S3 bucket with files with the following format

```
20220630_084021_abc.json
20220630_084031_def.json
20220630_084051_ghi.json
20220630_084107_abc.json
20220630_084118_def.json
```

So, I would like to get all the files that start with `20220630_0840*`.
So, I've tried to fetch them using multiple variations on the include pattern, so far I had used the followings:

```
 aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET/ LocalFolder  --include "20220630_0840*" --recursive
 aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET/ LocalFolder  --include "[20220630_0840]*" --recursive
 aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET/ LocalFolder  --include "20220630\_0840*" --recursive
```

None of them really work I'm getting all the files that have their name starting with `20220630`

Comment: Use `--exclude="*" --include "*/20220630_0840*"`

Comment: Check my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73766516/5285732 you can use rclone to sync/copy dirs according to patterns. In my answer I explained how to list the dirs, though if you read the docs a bit, you'll see that it's quite intuitive to use rclone